# How to add an extra command for a specific kernel module (command to be executed after the module is generated)

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver, gnu-make

Suppose I have a driver at drivers/platform/ab21/axpu.c and the driver is declared with `module_platform_driver` macro and I set the config so that the driver is compiled into a kernel module. Now I want to copy the drivers/platform/ab21/axpu.ko file to /srv/tftp directory whenever the module is newly built. How should I modify the Makefile?
I tried adding in drivers/platform/ab21/Makefile

```
axpu.ko:
    \cp axpu.ko /srv/tftp
```

or modifying in top Makefile

```
.PHONY: $(PHONY) xxx
xxx: drivers/platform/ab21/axpu.ko
    \cp ^$ /src/tftp/.
```

But both didn't work.

Comment: Doesn't really look like something that the `Makefile` of the module should worry about. Why not write a simple script that does `make` + `cp`?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, actually I was doing that. but I was curious. (for case when `make` generates some of the modules according to the modifications, it would be convenient to copy only the updated files to some directory)

Comment: Well, not exactly what you are looking for, but you could use `rsync` for that, it will only copy updated files.

Comment: Why do you have backslashes? What’s for?

Comment: Actually you can install a particular module using properly formed `make` command (**after** you have got a build done by regular `make` command).